# Laratable ambiguous colums on search

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I'm using Laravel 5's laratables. and in my `PartnersVehicles` model i have this function

```
    public static function laratablesQueryConditions($query)
    {
        $uid = Auth::id(); //user ID
        $pid = Partners::where('uid', $uid)->first(); //get partner ID

        return $query->select('partners_vehicles.id', 'partners_vehicles.year', 'vehicle_makes.make', 'partners_vehicles.model', 'vehicle_colors.color', 'partners_vehicles.created_at')
        ->join('vehicle_makes', 'vehicle_makes.id', '=', 'partners_vehicles.make')
        ->join('vehicle_colors', 'vehicle_colors.id', '=', 'partners_vehicles.color')
        ->where('partners_vehicles.partner_id', $pid->id);

    }
```

the table loads fine, but when I try and do an ajax search in the search box, i get this error below

Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'make' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `partners_vehicles` inner join `vehicle_makes` on `vehicle_makes`.`id` = `partners_vehicles`.`make` inner join `vehicle_colors` on `vehicle_colors`.`id` = `partners_vehicles`.`color` where `partners_vehicles`.`partner_id` = 7 and (`year` like %2% or `make` like %2% or `model` like %2% or `color` like %2%))

i tried changing my select to this, but still no luck

```
select('partners_vehicles.id', 'partners_vehicles.year', 'vehicle_makes.make AS `make`', 'partners_vehicles.model', 'vehicle_colors.color', 'partners_vehicles.created_at')
```

any idea how to fix this? what am i missing? Thanks

Comment: It appears to be unhappy with the part of the WHERE clause that's in parenthesis, specifically the 'make' column.  Where exactly is that part of the WHERE clause created?

Comment: @knot22 i have no idea, cant seem to find where its generated :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static function laratablesQueryConditions($query)
{
    $uid = Auth::id(); //user ID
    $pid = Partners::where('uid', $uid)->first(); //get partner ID
    $res=DB::table('partners_vehicles')
         ->select('partners_vehicles.id', 'partners_vehicles.year', 'vehicle_makes.make', 'partners_vehicles.model', 'vehicle_colors.color', 'partners_vehicles.created_at')
         ->join('vehicle_makes', 'vehicle_makes.id', '=', 'partners_vehicles.make')
         ->join('vehicle_colors', 'vehicle_colors.id', '=', 'partners_vehicles.color')
         ->where('partners_vehicles.partner_id','=', $pid->id)
         ->get();
   return $res;
}
```